# I don't understand Modules

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

I am trying to learn Zend Framework 3 and I have done the Album tutorial and another Blog tutorial. I've been writing straight php apps for about 3 years and wrote 2 web apps using Slim 3. I am trying to wrap my head around Modules. I don't quit understand what a module is. The way I understood Modules, is that a Module was a tiny app inside of the main app. I was trying to create 2 controllers in the same module and render different views from those controllers. I have searched all day and could not find a way to create two controllers and have them route to different views. But, I have found many examples of an app having 5 different modules all with only one controller and maybe different views that a class method would point to. Is it my understanding that a module should be created for every page? For example, a login module and an about module and a contact module?

module.config.php

```
    <?php

namespace Blog;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;


return [
    // this line opens the configuration fro the Route Manager
    'router' => [
        // open configuration for all possible routes
        'routes' => [
            // Define a new route called 'blog'
            'blog' => [
                // define 'literal' route type:
                'type' => Literal::class,
                // configure the route itself
                'options' => [
                    // listen to '/blog' as uri:
                    'route' => '/blog',
                    // define default controller and action to be called when
                    // this route is matched
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\ListController::class,
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                    'login' => [
                        'type' => Literal::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'route' => '/blog/login',
                            'defaults' => [
                                'controller' => Controller\LoginController::class,
                                'action' => 'login',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'aliases' => [
            Model\PostRepositoryInterface::class => Model\PostRepository::class,
        ],
        'factories' => [
            Model\PostRepository::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\ListController::class => Factory\ListControllerFactory::class,
            Controller\LoginController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_map' => [
            'login/login' => __DIR__ . '/../view/blog/login/login.phtml'
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view'
        ],
    ]
];
```

file structure

```
 |-- module
        |   |-- Application
        |   |   |-- config
        |   |   |   |-- module.config.php
        |   |   |-- src
        |   |   |   |-- Module.php
        |   |   |   |-- Controller
        |   |   |       |-- IndexController.php
        |   |   |-- test
        |   |   |   |-- Controller
        |   |   |       |-- IndexControllerTest.php
        |   |   |-- view
        |   |       |-- application
        |   |       |   |-- index
        |   |       |       |-- index.phtml
        |   |       |-- error
        |   |       |   |-- 404.phtml
        |   |       |   |-- index.phtml
        |   |       |-- layout
        |   |           |-- layout.phtml
        |   |-- Blog
        |       |-- config
        |       |   |-- module.config.php
        |       |-- src
        |       |   |-- Module.php
        |       |   |-- Controller
        |       |   |   |-- ListController.php
        |       |   |   |-- LoginController.php
        |       |   |-- Factory
        |       |   |   |-- ListControllerFactory.php
        |       |   |-- Model
        |       |       |-- Post.php
        |       |       |-- PostCommandInterface.php
        |       |       |-- PostRepository.php
        |       |       |-- PostRepositoryInterface.php
        |       |-- view
        |           |-- blog
        |               |-- list
        |               |   |-- index.phtml
        |               |-- login
        |                   |-- login.phtml
```

I'm working in the Blog module. When I call the LoginController.php I want it to show the login.phtml. If I comment out the blog route it will work, but when I uncomment the blog route I get a 'The requested URL could not be matched by routing.' error.

Comment: Controllers will render different views by default, since the default template name is based on the controller name. What was it you were doing that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing is not related to the template that is shown, so it sounds like you actually have a routing problem.

Your routing configuration is not structured correctly. It should look more like this:

```
return [
    // this line opens the configuration for the Route Manager
    'router' => [
        // open configuration for all possible routes
        'routes' => [
            // Define a new route called 'blog'
            'blog' => [
                // define 'literal' route type:
                'type' => Literal::class,
                // configure the route itself
                'options' => [
                    // listen to '/blog' as uri:
                    'route' => '/blog',
                    // define default controller and action to be called when
                    // this route is matched
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\ListController::class,
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => [                
                    'login' => [
                        'type' => Literal::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'route' => '/login',
                            'defaults' => [
                                'controller' => Controller\LoginController::class,
                                'action' => 'login',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Differences:

- The `'login'` route should be a child route, not part of the `blog` route options.
- I added `'may_terminate' => true` which makes the `/blog` route work (routes with child routes are not accessible by default)
- I changed `'route' => '/blog/login',` to `'route' => '/login',` in the login route. As it's a child of the blog you don't need to repeat the blog route's path.

Edit: if you want both routes at the top level instead:

```
return [
    // this line opens the configuration for the Route Manager
    'router' => [
        // open configuration for all possible routes
        'routes' => [
            // Define a new route called 'blog'
            'blog' => [
                // define 'literal' route type:
                'type' => Literal::class,
                // configure the route itself
                'options' => [
                    // listen to '/blog' as uri:
                    'route' => '/blog',
                    // define default controller and action to be called when
                    // this route is matched
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\ListController::class,
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'login' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/login',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\LoginController::class,
                        'action' => 'login',
                    ],
                ],
            ],                
        ],
    ],
```

This adds routes for `/blog` and `/login`. If you want the login page to be at `/blog/login` you'll have to edit the path in the login route appropriately.

Comment: So any route after the 'home' route is a child route?

Comment: No, routes defined within `child_routes` of another route are child routes. Anything else is a top level route.

Comment: Can I have 2 top level routes in the same module?

Comment: Sure, you can structure the routes however you like.

Comment: I guess this is where i'm confused. How would I create blog and login both as top level routes?

Comment: I've added a second example to my answer.

Comment: With the first example login would be at /blog/login. With the second example login would be at /login. Correct?